# app crashes in android studio emulator as soon as I modify the Java code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-emulator

Okay, so I opened **android studio** and created new project of empty activity.
I changed the layout of **xml** and modified the **xml** code without typing a single word in **java** file and run the android emulator and emulator works properly, but whenever I typed something (i.e. according to **java** code) in **java** file and run the android emulator, app crashes everytime.
I cant figure it out, what is happening with the **java** file.
plz assist me...

Comment: nothing you've posted so far actually helps us figure out what's wrong. find the stack trace, research the error, resolve it yourself so that you don't have these issues in future. when posting here on SO, you need to include enough _relevant_ detail for us to recreate here, at the moment, you haven't _nearly_ done that

Comment: ok, got it! I'll try to be more relevant next time

Comment: always ask yourself if you'd be able to understand/recreate your own question without any knowledge of the situation. you are welcome to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67330918/edit) your post to add more detail

Answer (score 1):

Does this java file appear in AndroidManifest.xml? You can find this file in the directory app/manifests. For each java file associated with an activity, an activity entry must be made in this file. This manifest file is what let's your app know which activities it can run. Thus, if you try to run code for an activity that is not defined in the manifest, the app crashes immediately. If your java activity is called "ActivityOne", you want to have  inside the  .. /> tags of this file.

[Here is what the AndroidManifest should look like for an app with a MainActivity and another activity named "ActivityOne"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z079b.png)

Additionally, you can click "run" on the bottom bar in android studio to view the application output as it runs. Error messages upon app crashes will also be displayed here. Posting a screenshot of your error message along with your word description of the problem is the best way to ensure that those who want to help you have enough information to do so.

[This is what the bottom bar and "run" button look like, as well as an example of a live application output stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ1IL.png)

If the problem does not appear to be with AndroidManifest, please post a follow up with a picture of your error message.

Comment: ok, I run it again and it is showing me NullPointer exception what is it?